# Before print event in Visio Interop

Tags: ms-office, interop, office-interop, visio

I'm using the Visio interop in C#. I'm creating an application which set up watermark into visio document. I need to add a specific watermark when visio document is printing, but visio has no event like "Document_BeforePrint" in MS Word. Now I can only handle the CTRL+P key pressing, but it's not enough, cause users print document using "Menu -> Printing". Is it possible to handle this action?

Comment: Do you need to set the watermark just before printing or could you set it earlier? I ask because you can create a shape which is not view-able but is printable.

Comment: I need to set it earlier.

Answer (score 0):

Create a print only layer, either through the [UI](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/add-a-layer-adcb61d3-5e8b-431e-bb9d-4a35eae28e48) or [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/visio.layers.add). Set Visible to false and Print to true on the layer. Add what ever shapes you want to the layer. They won't be displayed in Visio but will appear when you print.

Comment: It works good, but I need to select which watermark I should use before printing.